# Solution to #13 of SQL Join in SQLZoo

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The link is http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation. Question No.13.
Now I can list all the matches as long as there is at least one goal with the code:

```
SELECT mdate, 
       team1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score1, 
       team2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score2 FROM
    game JOIN goal ON (id = matchid)
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

However there are some games the score of which is 0:0. My code can't display these games, and can't find other available solutions. Really hope someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT mdate, 
       team1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score1, 
       team2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score2 FROM
    game LEFT JOIN goal ON (id = matchid)
    GROUP BY mdate,team1,team2
    ORDER BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

You want to GROUP BY columns without aggregate functions in the SELECT and use a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

Try `LEFT JOIN` insted of `JOIN`. Because you need to show all games even if there are no goals.

Comment: Your brief answer works! Thank you. I gave the point to the other guy because he is earlier.

Comment: @shaosh interesting thing I noticed 3 years later lol. If we look at answered time we will see that my answer was earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT G.mDate
      ,G.Team1
      ,ISNULL( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goal WHERE teamid = G.Team1), 0) AS Team1_Goals 
      ,G.Team2
      ,ISNULL( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goal WHERE teamid = G.Team2), 0) AS Team2_Goals      
FROM Game G 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM goal 
              WHERE matchid = G.matchid)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL engine remove the `ORDER BY` clause from the accepted answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33185488)